# Jquery $() - what does it return, and what is $()[0]?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at an example of how to use jqGrid, which is a jQuery plugin.

It's drawing a grid in a div with an id of 'list'.

It creates the grid with `$('#list').jqGrid(...)`.

But it populates the grid with `$('#list')[0].addJSONData(...)`.

I've been looking around the web for tutorials on jQuery, trying to understand the difference, and I've found nothing that addresses what is - to me - the most fundamental question in using it.

What does `$()` return?  Does it return a jquery object that contains a DOM element?  Does it return a jquery object that contains an array of DOM elements?  Does it return a DOM element to which additional jQuery functions have been added?

And what then, is `$()[0]`?  If `$()` returned a jQuery object that contained an array of DOM elements, I'd expect it to be the div with the id 'list', but `addJSONData` isn't a DOM method, it's a jqGrid method.  Does jqGrid add that method to all of the DOM elements in the array?

===== ADDED ======

If $() returns a jquery object that contains an arrray of DOM objects, why does $()[0] refer to an object that contains an addJSONData method? addJSONData is not a DOM method, it's a jqGrid method.

Comment: Some of these answerers should tidy up the answer space.  Do we need to have 6 answers that all say "$() returns a jQuery object" ?

Comment: All you need to know and more:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` returns a collection of elements based on the selector.  So `$('.help')` would return all elements with a class of `.help`.  `$('.help')[0]` would give you the first element.

Answer (score 4):

`$()` is a jquery selector, it takes css expression and turn it into jQuery object, `$` is actually a shorthand of jQuery, i.e. `jQuery()` and `$()` are the same.

`$()[0]` simply takes the non jQuery object, so if you do `$('#someId')[0]`, it's the same as `getElementById('someId');`

Comment: This is correct, but you should explain *why* your second statement is true.

Answer (score 2):

$() is an alias for the [jQuery() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).  It returns a jQuery object and and elements that match the provided selector.  If matched elements were found, $()[0] would give you the first DOM element.

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object, when used with a selector, returns an array of DOM elements. In this case, `$('#list')` represents an array (with one slot, since this is an ID) of items that match the ID `'#list'`.

Answer (score 0):

$() returns a jQuery object that contains a set of matched elements. Indexing into the jQuery object via $()[0] returns the first matched DOM object.

```
var docWrappedInJQuery = $('document');
var bareDoc = $('document')[0];
assert((document === docWrappedInJQuery) === false);
assert((document === bareDoc) === true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is the same as calling `jQuery()`. Documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Keep in mind calling `$(function() { })` is a shortcut to calling `$(document).ready(function() { });`